# In a single page app that has a list of things, i.e. 'tasks', is it best to allow the user to edit them in place

Tags: usability

Say I develop a single page app using Angular that displays a list of todo tasks, for example:

```
   Task: Grocery Shopping
   Due:  10/01/17
   [Done][Delete]

   Task: Call Mobile Company
   Due:  23/02/17
   [Done][Delete]
```

From a usability perspective, do you think it's better to have users be able to edit the task name 'Grocery Shopping' and date in place as it is in the list with no confirmation that it's been updated (it just happens behind the scenes when it detects a change), or is it better to pop up a modal with that information then hit 'done'? Or is it better to allow them to edit it in place and then have a 'done editing' button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Providing feedback to the user is a MUST

No matter which approach you take, the user should be given a response/feedback of some sort.

Say, you go with the *inline edit* approach, there must be a confirmation feedback of some sort like:

- Loading animation that turns into a checkbox
- A confirmation notification
- A significant change in element styling (size, shape, font weight, tonality, borders...)
- A pop-up confirmation (not recommended)

If not, simply add a **Done** or a **Save** button

Comment: Yes I understand, I will take your advice... Do you have a preference between inline / modal edit of an item?

Comment: Modals and other interrupts should be avoided when not strictly necessary.  Is there a reason that editing one item should hide other content or lock me out of other page actions?  Sometimes our knee-jerk is to "simplify" by pushing to reduced views, modal or otherwise, but this isn't always beneficial.  If editing can be accomplished readily inline, there is no need for additional views.

Comment: Hmm okay so edit inline where possible and always provide feedback. Helpful :) thanks so much for answering me.